# ¿Hay manera de iniciar un Spinner en una posición? Xamarin Android

Tags: spinner, xamarin.android

Quisiera poder iniciar un spinner en una posición específica, mandando al spinner como parámetro un int, para iniciar en esa posición

```
public void LoadSublinea()
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            var tblProveedor = db.Table<SubLinea>().Where(x => x.Borrado == false).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
            ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var prove in tblProveedor)
            {
                LstSublinea.Add(prove);
                lst.Add(prove.Nombre);
            }
            string[] arr = (String[])lst.ToArray(typeof(string));
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);
            spnSublineaPopUp.Adapter = adapter;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré una solución en Android Java, y parece que funciona perfecto igual aquí en Xamarin Android, se utiliza la funcion Spinner.SetSelection(int); 
Créditos: https://carmazone.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/inicializacion-personalizada-de-spinner/
Quedó así:

```
public void LoadSublinea()
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            var tblProveedor = db.Table<SubLinea>().Where(x => x.Borrado == false).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
            ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var prove in tblProveedor)
            {
                LstSublinea.Add(prove);
                lst.Add(prove.Nombre);
            }
            string[] arr = (String[])lst.ToArray(typeof(string));
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);
            spnSublineaPopUp.Adapter = adapter;
//Se agrega la función al final
                spnSublineaPopUp.SetSelection(IdSublinea);
            }
```